# Normal groups and homomorphism are the same, and this gives an approach to isomorphism theorem?

Tags: normal-subgroups, group-isomorphism, group-homomorphism

I was reading a post [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/math/comments/2jvrv9/how_to_internalize_the_isomorphism_theorems_from/) that give some interesting approach about isomorphism theorem (see quote). But there are some things I don't understand. What exactly does this mean?

> The Second Isomorphism Theorem says that the homomorphism F is the
>   same on the restriction to H (by restricting the kernal) as it is on
>   the smallest subgroup that contains both K and H. F cannot tell the
>   difference between them.

And also the explanation for this

> The Third Isomorphism Theorem tells us that making this stop into G'
>   does not affect anything

is not so clear to me, what exactly does it mean by does not affect anything?

This was the original post :

> The isomorphism theorems overall tell us that Homomorphisms and Normal
>   Subgroups are essentially the same thing. Or, alternatively,
>   Homomorphisms are classified by their Kernals.
>
> The First Isomorphism Theorem sets up the correspondence: For every
>   Normal Subgroup K, there is a "unique" surjective Homomorphism with
>   kernal K. (I use quotes because we can compose with any isomorphism of
>   G/K to get another, but we can see these as the same) Any other
>   homomorphism with kernal K will contain the image of this homomorphism
>   as an ordinary subgroup.
>
> That is good and all, but we can do various things within G that may
>   change what a homomorphism looks like. We want to classify some of
>   these things.
>
> If we have a homomorphism F from G with kernal K and a subgroup H of
>   G, how does F behave when we restrict to H? First, we know that the
>   kernal is going to be K∩H, simply by definition. But if we look at the
>   subgroup KH, then we are still essentially restricting to K (because
>   for kh in KH, F(kh)=F(h), so it only depends on K) but this new group
>   contains H now. This can be see as the smallest subgroup of G that
>   contains both K and H. The Second Isomorphism Theorem says that the
>   homomorphism F is the same on the restriction to H (by restricting the
>   kernal) as it is on the smallest subgroup that contains both K and H.
>   F cannot tell the difference between them. You should view the Second
>   Isomorphism Theorem as the Isomorphism Theorem of Function
>   Restriction.
>
> What happens if we compose two functions? If F is a surjective
>   function from G to H, but we can factor this into a composition of two
>   functions A from G to G' and B from G' to H (so F=B*A), then what
>   happens to the kernals? The Third Isomorphism Theorem tells us that
>   making this stop into G' does not affect anything. If N is the kernal
>   of F, then the image of F is isomorphis to G/N. But if A has kernal K,
>   then we need G'=G/K and the image of N is going to be N/K. Then going
>   from G' to H is going to have kernal N/K and so H=G'/(N/K). You should
>   see the Third Isomorphism Theorem as the Isomorphism Theorem of
>   Function Composition.
>
> It's a shame that the Isomorphism Theorems are all done in terms of
>   quotient groups, which are dry and usually very unmotivated. The focus
>   of an intro to Group Theory course should be on Homomorphisms and
>   Group Actions rather than on group structure. It really helps motivate
>   things, put them into context, apply more fluidly into other areas of
>   math and you still get all the structure theorems you could ask for.
>
> The First Isomorphism Theorem could be stated as such:
>
> If K is a normal subgroup, then there is a homomorphism with kernal K
>   and any two such homomorphisms have isomorphic images. Call the image
>   G/K.
>
> So we define G/K as the image of the homomorphism guaranteed by the
>   First Isomorphism Theorem and then the proof of it would just be the
>   typical construction of it. This really shows that the structure of
>   G/K is determined as the image of a homomorphism instead of confusing
>   things with cosets. Save cosets for Group Actions.